# How to display message box when starting up an Inno Setup installer

Tags: inno-setup, messagebox

How to display a message box information, when starting up an installer made in Inno Setup?

Like this setup of Reloaded Games does:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Call the [`MsgBox` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_msgbox) from the [`InitializeSetup` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=InitializeSetup):

```pascal
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  MsgBox('Some message.', mbInformation, MB_OK);

  Result := True;
end;
```